# Append stylesheet from child component laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a master blade template and a component.
I tried to include my stylesheet only for my component, not the whole template how can I do that?

My attempt was using `@stack` as described [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#stacks)

`view/layouts/master.blade.php`

```php
<head>
    ...
    ...
    @stack('styles')
</head>
```

`view/books/index.blade.php`

```
...
...
@push('styles')
    <link href="{{ asset(css/styles.css) }}" rel="stylesheet">
@endpush
...
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved, my css file was on resources folder, it should be on a public folder